# Is it possible to have a background service to check if we have internet on iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, background-process, reachability

Is it possible to have a background service to check if we have internet on iOS?

I understand that background service in iOS is only for specific tasks, but this doesn't seem to be one.

Maybe there is another way?

What about scheduling local notifications to run a process on the background. is that possible?

Comment: "I understand that background service in iOS is only for specific tasks, but this doesn't seem to be one." Correct; this would be the problem in trying to ship this app, even if you could figure out a way to make it work. Using local notifications to trick the system into running you is definitely running afoul of app store rules too (the "trick the system" part is the give-away…) You'll need to go back to what problem you're really solving.

Comment: Whats your final goal? I mean, checking internet reachability, would not, in itself, be a requirement for an app. If you explain what you mean to achieve by checking reachability, you could find ways to achieve it without doing what your are trying to do. Simplest example would be downloading content in background : https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW5

Comment: You are doing something sneaky? HA! Can try private methods (idk).